# How to insert any sequence of characters into a string, except for the given one?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regex for `\namefunction[~argument inside~]` and in the line `argument inside` there should not be a sequence of characters `[~` and `~]` how can I do this? I tried to use `(?!   )` like this `(?!(\[\~|\~\]))` but this doesn't work. The final expression turned out like this `\\[a-z]+(\[\~(?!(\[\~|\~\]))\~\])+`.

To make it easier for you to understand, for example: any sequence of characters in brackets that does not contain the sequence `ahah`

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of input and expected output?

Comment: @ankr For example input `some text \function[~asdasdasd~]  sometext2  \function2[~dsf~sdf~]  some text 3 \function3[~sdfs~]dfsdf~]` Output: `array ["\function[~asdasdasd~]", "\function2[~dsf~sdf~]", "\function3[~sdfs~]"]` or `array ["\function[~asdasdasd~]", "\function2[~dsf~sdf~]", "\function3[~sdfs~]dfsdf~]"]`

Comment: It doesn't matter which array is returned, the main thing is at least some

Comment: Now it returns the whole string `array ["\function[~asdasdasd~]  sometext2  \function2[~dsf~sdf~]  some text 3 \function3[~sdfs~]dfsdf~]"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

You need to use [lazy quantifier(`*?`)](https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy) to get as many groups as possible:

```js
const regex = /\\.*?\[~.*?~\]/g;

console.log(`some text \\function[~asdasdasd~]  sometext2  \\function2[~dsf~sdf~]  some text 3 \\function3[~sdfs~]dfsdf~]`.match(regex));
```